# Как вызвать только цифровую клавиатуру для ввода номера в input?

Tags: html, css, input, inputmask

```
<div class="input-prepend">
<input class="input-medium focused" id="mephone" tabindex="2" name="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="+7 (___) ___ - __ - __" /></div>
```

Как это можно тут сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое простое `type="text"` заменить на `type="tel"`

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov а самое сложное? Если не менять type?

Comment: Сложное - это к js-никам. Замените теги в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего `type="number"` или `type="tel"`. http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type

Comment: Спасибо, всем, принципе то, что нужно.

Comment: При использование маски (например +7(999)999-9999)) если указывать number то маска стирается и может заблокироваться ввод(в зависимости от используемого плагина для маски), поэтому для случая с маской имнно вариант tel.